# Emulator Problem

Tags: android-emulator

When I'm lunching an app the emulator is to big for the screen and it is on the side.

What to do?
Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 0):

You should learn [emulator tutorial](http://www.android.encke.net/android-emulator-tutorial.html) and also see here: [emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)

Answer (score 0):

The emulator screen can be rotated by pressing:

- F11
- 7 on your Number pad

Which one to use may vary by machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it by changing orientation or you can reduce screen resolution when you create avd it'll ask for skin select hvga.If you want to modify current emulator screen size just go to window--->sdk and avd manager--> and it'll display list of avds you have select one  avd and edit it's skin property to hvga or whatever you want.